# for loop not counting past 2 columns - even though there is data in the 3rd column in excel worksheet

Tags: c#, macros

```
string workbookPath = filePath;
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
Excel.Range range;

int rCnt = 0;
int cCnt = 0;

xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

int rowCount = range.Rows.Count;
int columnCount = range.Columns.Count;

string[][] myArray = new string[rowCount][];

for (rCnt = 1; rCnt < rowCount; rCnt++)
{
    myArray[rCnt] = new string[columnCount];

    for (cCnt = 1; cCnt < columnCount; cCnt++)
    {

        object str = (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).get_Value();
----->  myArray[rCnt][cCnt] = str == null ? string.Empty : str.ToString();


    }
}


xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
xlApp.Quit();

return myArray;
```

Above is the code for uploading an excel file to a sql database.
Essentially when I pass over the rCnt and cCnt variables where the ----> is above... the row count goes up once everytime the column count goes up twice ... I want to the column count to go up to 3, or however many usable columns there are.

The reason it's doing this could be that in the first row of the excel csv - there is nothing in the cell - however, in the 4-5th row, there is data in the 3rd column.

Could anyone glance at what I am missing?

Any questions / help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should start both `rCnt` and `cCnt` at 0

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply - this is the error i receive when such happens
on the line above the ---->
COMException was unhandled
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand: if you start both at 0 you get this exception?

Comment: yup, for (rCnt = 0
for (cCnt = 0

Comment: now, at the line of code:
string StoreNumber = row[mapping[customer_no]["StoreNumber"]];
i get an error.
The way this works is, the store number is found from the column number that i specified as such:
mapping["TRGT"]["StoreNumber"] = 0;
0 zero being column 1. 

The error - NullReferenceException was unhandled: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the point, but shouldn't you initialize `myArray` like `string[][] myArray = new string[rowCount][columnCount];`? You're letting column empty.

Comment: How else would i initialize myArray

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that your code `string[][] myArray = new string[rowCount][];` and `myArray[rCnt] = new string[columnCount];` is allowing you to return a jagged array and you're going beyond those bounds somehow. UsedRange can sometimes be finicky (especially if you've deleted data - the range doesn't shrink down to fit your current data).

This code works fine for me, I use it a bit at work. COM entry/release code not included, I can add that later if you want it.

```
public string[,] ReadArray(int SheetNumber)
{
  worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(SheetNumber);
  Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;

  //Get array, use range values. Not always correct, esp if user has deleted data. Ignore null values
  Object[,] arr = range.Cells.Value;
  string[,] output = new string[arr.GetLength(0), arr.GetLength(1)];

  for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
      //If nothing in the cell, write a blank
      if (arr[i + 1, j + 1] == null)
      {
        output[i, j] = "";
        continue;
      }
      //else, write the output
      output[i, j] = arr[i + 1, j + 1].ToString();
    }
  }

  if (range != null)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
  if (worksheet != null)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);

  return output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response - if you could provide the COM entry / release code - that would be helpful.

Comment: Also - I am getting an error for the following line: Object[,] arr = range.Cells.Value


Error 27 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'object[*,*]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)